# Filter dataobject by page id SilvertStripe3

Tags: php, oop, silverstripe

I have a page type **"class Test extends Page"** and it has many **'TestBlocks' => 'TestBlock'**, then the CMS users enter new data to the fields on CMS back-end and what I need is to get these values from **"class TestBlock extends DataObject"** and to create a form with them. Basically that data becomes question, but I'm not sure how to get it inside my Test controller the right way. When i try the get method for dataobect it returns all values from all pages from the pagetype instead that particular page code below:

```
class Test_Controller extends Page_Controller
{
private static $allowed_actions = array(
    'TestForm',

);

public function TestForm()
{

    $players = MultiQuestion::get();
    echo $players->QuestionText;
    $array = [];
    foreach ($players as $player) {
        $array[] = TextField::create($player->QuestionText)->setFieldHolderTemplate('Field_Holder');
    }

    $fieldGroup1 = CompositeField::create(
        $array

    )->setName('FieldGroup1');

    $fields = FieldList::create($fieldGroup1);
    $actions = FieldList::create(
        FormAction::create('submit', 'Get Results')->addExtraClass('get_results')
    );
    $form = Form::create($this, __function__, $fields, $actions);

    return $form;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$testBlocks = $this->TestBlocks()` assuming that you have the relationships set up correctly.

**TestBlock.php**

```
class TestBlock extends DataObject {
  static $has_one = array(
    'Test' => 'Test'
  );
}
```

**Test.php**

```
class Test extends Page {
  static $has_many = array(
    'TestBlocks' => 'TestBlock'
  );
}

class Test_Controller extends Page_Controller {

  public function TestForm() {
    $testBlocks = $this->TestBlocks();
    //other code
  }
}
```

Comment: what if you have inside the TestBlock:                                                                   static $has_many = array('TestBlocks2' => 'TestBlock2'); how owuld you get that has many if it nested further? 
$this->TestBlocks()->TestBlocks2();